# How to assign the table value to stored procedure parameter using entityframeworkextra

Tags: angularjs, entity-framework, model-view-controller

Im sending Html table values to mvc controller action method using angular. This is my angular code.

```
      var feedbackdata = {

        SpeakerRatings: $scope.SpeakerTable  // This scope contains two rows of table data
    };

    FeedBackFormfac.InsertFeedback(feedbackdata).then(function (data) {
        alert(data.data)
    })

  fac.InsertFeedback = function (d) {

    return $http({
        url: '/Feedback/Insert',
        method: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(d),
        headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'}
    });
};
```

And im receiving this json data in my controller action method. And im trying to insert this data into my database using entityframeworkextra. But im not able to bind the table values to parameter SpeakerRatings.

```
  public JsonResult Insert(FeedBackFormVM F)
    {
          var procedure = new InsertFeedbackSP()
            {
               SpeakerRatings = new List<SpeakerRatingsUDT>
               {
                   new SpeakerRatingsUDT()

               }
            }

    }
```

In above code im trying to bind the data coming from angular i.e (object F contains Html table values) to Userdefined table type class which is created using entityframeworkextra and my userdefined table class will be like this

```
 [UserDefinedTableType("SpeakerRatingsType")]
public class SpeakerRatingsUDT
{
    [UserDefinedTableTypeColumn(1)]
    public int SpeakerId { get; set; }
    [UserDefinedTableTypeColumn(2)]
    public string SpeakerName { get; set; }
    [UserDefinedTableTypeColumn(3)]
    public int Rating { get; set; } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im receiving Html table values into List with type of UserdefinedType class

```
   public JsonResult Insert(FeedBackFormVM F)
    {
          List<SpeakerRatingsVM> newdata = F.SpeakerRatings;
          var procedure = new InsertFeedbackSP()
            {
               SpeakerRatings = newdata.Select(x => new SpeakerRatingsUDT { 
      SpeakerId=x.SpeakerId,SpeakerName=x.SpeakerName,Rating=x.Rating}).ToList()

            }

    }
```